# AWS S3 Transfer Utility Multipart delay in resuming uploads (iOS Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, aws-sdk, awss3transferutility

Whenever i start uploading files with multipart upload using transfer utility and if the file size is larger like 100mb once i kill the app and launch the app again it gives a delay in resuming the task, But the transfer utility uploadData function does not gives this delay it resumes the upload quickly, Anybody seems to know what's the issue

What i think is with larger files the multipart assembles the file again and then resume it where we left off, But transfer utility uploadData function doesn't do this

```
transferUtility?.uploadUsingMultiPart(fileURL: fileUrl, bucket: self.bucketName, key: myFileKey, contentType: contenType, expression: expression, completionHandler: completionHandler).continueWith { (task) -> Any? in
       if let error = task.error {
                print("error is: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
       if let task = task.result {
                
       }
    return nil
}


transferUtility?.uploadFile(fileUrl, bucket: self.bucketName, key: fileKey, contentType: "image", expression: expression, completionHandler: completionHandler).continueWith { (task) -> Any? in
        if let error = task.error {
            print("error is: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
        return nil
}
```

Comment: Your question is not clear - can you provide code samples for the 2 scenarios you are describing? And what is the question or problem? You don't want the delay? Want to know why the delay is there? What the delay is for? We need morinfo.

Comment: I have added the code, The problem is i don't want the delay, The delay is there because i already mention above i think multipart break the files into parts and when we resume it it assembles the parts again to resume the upload so it takes more time